# Default sort order in Windows folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I am running Windows 7 and I have a folder "Dropbox" inside my Documents folder. However, every time I restart Explorer and enter this folder, it is sorted by mutation date. I'd like to have it default sorted by name, which is still default in all other folders, however not in this one.

Please let me know if there is a way to define this properly! Thanks in advance!

**Note**: I actually found out that this is in every folder or library now, not only in some folders. This is the standard sort behaviour when I open explorer the first time.

Comment: Do you view this folder via the Libraries feature or do you view it directly?

Comment: I tried both but it's the same on both ways

Comment: If you right click on the folder in direct view and choose _customize_, is the contents of the first drop-down menu ("Optimize this folder for:") set to the same value as a folder where the sort feature defaults to name?

Comment: Didn't work with all possible values at "Optimize this folder for:"...

Comment: Note: I actually found out that this is in every folder or library now, not only in some folders. This is the standard sort behaviour when I open explorer the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite weird... after more than 2 months of always having to sort it, now the files are sorted the correct way. I do not know why this works now.